# 'reality check' - looking for a verb

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

As I mentioned in the questions, I'm looking for a verb to use with this expression.

Can I say "I did my reality check?

My_examples:
Let’s say that something is different than I thought. Can I say:”I did reality check, and American Dream isn’t alive anymore.” or another example “I did reality check, and my job is less exciting than I had thought before.”

What other verbs can be used with "reality check"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other examples might be

> I **had** a reality check.
>   It **was** a reality check.
>   It **created** a reality check.
>   It **resulted** in a reality check.
>   It **became** a reality check.

depends what you want to say.

Comment: Can I say:”I did reality check, and American Dream isn’t alive anymore.” or another example “I did reality check, and my job is less exciting than I had thought before.

Comment: "I did **a** reality check and **the** American Dream isn't alive anymore", you need to use "**a**" to sound more native. "I did **a** reality check, and my job is less exciting than I thought before.", the second part of your sentence is perfect and means you already started your job when you thought it would be more exciting. "I did **a** reality check, and my job is less exciting than I expected." means before starting your job you thought it would be very exciting (maybe why you applied for the job), but has not lived up to your expectations.

Comment: @Peter And can "reality check" be used as a verb, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

A related idiom is "to take stock (of something)", which means to assess a situation, especially in anticipation of making an important decision.

> I **took stock** of my situation and no longer think I'm in the right job.